# Hangfire has no active servers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

After publishing ASP MVC application, Hangfire Dashboard says, that it has no active servers. Tried to restart, rebuild, remove Hangfire's tables in DB - no success. 
OWIN Startup class:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .UseSqlServerStorage(@"HangfireStorage");

            var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
                Queues = new[] { "critical", "default" }
            };

            app.UseHangfireServer(options);

            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
            {
                AuthorizationFilters = new[] { new MyRestrictiveAuthorizationFilter() }
            });
            var hangfireUpdatingCron = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HangfireUpdatingPlayersCron"];
            var hangfireUpdatingLeagueMatchesCron = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HangfireUpdatingLeagueMatchesCron"];
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => SteamParser.ResetAllUpdatings());
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => SteamParser.UpdateAllPlayers());
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => SteamParser.UpdateAllPlayers(), hangfireUpdatingCron);
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => SteamParser.UpdateLeagueMatches(), hangfireUpdatingLeagueMatchesCron);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same problem here, with very similar setup.  2 out of 3 applications (separate databases) work; one says "There are no active servers" in the dashboard, even though there are plenty of successful-looking messages from Hangfire.BackgroundJobServer in the log4net logs.

Comment: There's an old open [issue](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/223) for this, but it looks like it could use some attention/help.

Comment: THIS Helped to me:  var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
                Queues = new[] { "critical", "default" },
                 ServerName = "Hangfire:1"
            };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, working for me now. Perhaps your situation has a similar solution. Paraphrasing from my update to that [issue](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/223):

My problem was specifically that I was running multiple applications in the same app pool, so the default "machinename:PID" naming scheme was not unique. But each app was pointed to its own separate database. So there was a race on startup/deploy and only one of the apps got to claim the single `BackgroundJobServer` as its own.  But no errors logged; everything looked fine.

The answer is in the [docs](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/running-multiple-server-instances.html): "Since the defaults values provide uniqueness only on a process level, you should to handle it manually, if you want to run different server instances inside the same process"

But the important point is that this situation includes multiple applications running under the same app pool, which is a single process.

Furthermore, when I attempted to implement the change suggested in the doc (setting a unique `BackgroundJobServerOptions.ServerName`), it errored out due to the maxlength problem mentioned in [this comment](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/running-multiple-server-instances.html#comment-2067804250). My solution was to use something shorter than a GUID for uniqueness. In my case, I used the application's name.

Answer (score 4):

> Hi there! Background job server instances now (since 1.5.0-beta1) use
>   GUID-based unique identifiers for each instance, so there is no need
>   to set any magic server names.

Ref: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/223

My issue was simply a forgotten line of code after an authorization problem with hangfire.

I just forgot to add:

```
app.UseHangfireServer();
```

So obviously the dashboard was initialized

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard('/hangfire', someOptions);
```

However the server was not running.

Coming up with a new damn problem(hangfire...), so gonna tackle that one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This helped to me:
In OWIN Startup class I've added  BackgroundJobServerOptions with ServerName:

```
var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
                Queues = new[] { "critical", "default" },
                 ServerName = "Hangfire:1"
            };
```

Comment: My fix was this, but with just the server name set to a string of my choosing.